# How to print key and values as one from a dictionary excluding None

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have coded something very simple such as:

```
data = ["39", "40.5", "41", "42", "42.5", "43", "44", "44.5", "45", "45.5", "46"]

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(data):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 20:
        print('\n'.join(data[i:j]))
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    print("if characterCount")
    print('\n'.join(data[i:]))
```

However this works very well when is based on a list however I have created a dict that looks like:

```
data = {
    '39': ' - (3)',
    '40.5': ' - (4)',
    '41': None,
    '42': ' - (16)',
    '42.5': None,
    '43': ' - (36)',
    '44': ' - (78)',
    '44.5': None,
    '45': ' - (30)',
    '45.5': ' - (12)',
    '46': None
}
```

and when I run the code with the dict, it returns: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'` in row: `print('\n'.join(data[i:j]))`

My question is, how can I print the key and values as a one value and if a dict has None as value then we just print the key without the "None" value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you can't access items in a dictionary using slicing syntax - they must be accessed directly using their key.

The simplest way is to get the keys as a list and then loop it, check if the value isn't None and then concatenate the contents and print it.

```
dict_keys = list(data.keys())
for index, key in enumerate(dict_keys):
    if data[key]:
        print(dict_keys[index] + data[key])
    else:
        print(dict_keys[index])
```

Comment: I think this might be the solution but I have no idea how I can add this part of code in the code I have given because I still do need the `if len(item) + characterCount > 20:` as well as `if characterCount:`. Is it possible to combine your code to mine?